# How to watch when the Slidable changes state on Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-animation, listtile

I'm utilize o [Slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable) on app Flutter and put as ListTile child.

So far ok.

I'm problem is i would like when I slide it to the left the text keeps appearing on the screen, as shown in the image below.(Red == Title)

[image]

At the moment the text is hidden when I swipe, as per the image.(Red == Title)
[image]

I saw that when I swipe this attribute changes state `Slidable.of(context)?.animation.isCompleted`

And I also verified that in my Row title of ListTile, if I line up the title as End, the title will appear msm by swiping.

So I thought, as this `Slidable.of(context)?.animation.isCompleted` attribute changes state I align my Row to Start or End.

But I couldn't find a way to monitor this attribute, so that when it changes I can rebuild my Row. I tried to put it as Stream but I wasn't successful. Because it looks like it doesn't generate an event, it just changes the value.

I don't know how I could do it, if anyone has any tips...

Code:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return Slidable(
        key: const ValueKey(1),
        endActionPane: ActionPane(
          motion: const DrawerMotion(),
          children: [
            SlidableAction(
              onPressed: (ctx) => {
                Get.to(() => const CredentialOperationScreen(),
                    arguments:
                        RouteDetailCredential(itemCredential: itemCredential))
              },
              backgroundColor: ConstsColors.orangeAccent,
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
              icon: Icons.info_outline,
            ),
            SlidableAction(
              onPressed: (ctx) => {
                Get.to(() => const CredentialOperationScreen(),
                    arguments:
                        RouteDeleteCredential(itemCredential: itemCredential))
              },
              backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(219, 32, 32, 1),
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
              icon: Icons.delete_outline,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Builder(
          builder: (ctx) {
            return Container(
                child: _listTile(ctx),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                        bottom:
                            BorderSide(color: ConstsColors.greyColorOpacity))));
          },
        ));
  }

  Widget _listTile(context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Icon(
            itemCredential.icon,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              itemCredential.name,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onTap: () => {
        Slidable.of(context)?.animation.isCompleted == true
            ? Slidable.of(context)?.close()
            : Slidable.of(context)?.openEndActionPane()
      },
      trailing: const Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline, color: Colors.green),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh update, include the code.